# Buttons disabled when asking for location

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a sports app, but when I request location the buttons stop functioning.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

     public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
           Button btnLogout;
           Button btnBair;
           Button btnVoir;
           Button btzFair;

           FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
           private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
            private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS ;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
                btnLogout= findViewById(R.id.Logout);
                btnBair= findViewById(R.id.button3);
                btnVoir= findViewById(R.id.button4);
                btzFair= findViewById(R.id.button5);

                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HomeActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);




                    return;
                }




                    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent hom= new Intent(HomeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(hom);


                    }
                });
                btzFair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent fair= new Intent(HomeActivity.this, FutbolActivity.class);
                        startActivity(fair);


                    }
                });
                btnBair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent hom= new Intent(HomeActivity.this, BasketActivity.class);
                        startActivity(hom);


                    }
                });
                btnVoir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent hom= new Intent(HomeActivity.this, VoleiActivity.class);
                        startActivity(hom);


                    }
                });
                }


        }
```

Comment: Hi. Which button exactly stops working and do you get any errors logged?

Comment: all of them, no i dont get any errors logged. they just function when i go two time back with the phone button.

Comment: It looks like all of your button's onClickListeners will only be set when the user has already granted the location permissions for your app. Have you tried granting the permissions on the app's settings, restart your activity, and then check if the buttons work?

Comment: it was the return, i ereased it and done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `return`  in your

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(){...}
```

I dont think it should be there. Delete it and see what happens